# restart setinterval a new position

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a "setinterval" to change my slides. With a button to change the slide. But once i click the button to change slide the "setinterval" will reset to where it was +1.

I want it to restart my +1 button

https://jsfiddle.net/8s6r3qay/

```
<section class="testimony">
<div class="testimony__content">

  <article class="testimony__content--pers">
    <div class="pers"></div>
    <p class="comment"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
    <p class="name">Gabrielle, 35 ans</p>
  </article>

  <aside class="aside hide-xs">
    <div class="bulletOrange pers1" onclick="stopSliderPers(0)"></div>
    <div class="bulletGrey pers2" onclick="stopSliderPers(1)"></div>
    <div class="bulletGrey pers3" onclick="stopSliderPers(2)"></div>
  </aside>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adopted a previous answer of mine for an image slider to add buttons that will let you jump to a specific slide and have the slideshow continue from there. Perhaps it has some code you can reuse in your solution.

```js
const
  delayBetweenPictures = 2000,
  numberOfPictures = 4,
  initialPicture = 1,
  image = document.getElementById('slideshow'),
  slideControl = document.getElementById('slide-control');
  
let 
  timeoutId;
  
function moveHighlight(pictureIndex) {
  const 
    oldButton = slideControl.querySelector('.highlight'),
    newButton = slideControl.querySelector(`[data-index="${pictureIndex}"]`);
    
  if (oldButton !== null) {
    oldButton.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
  
  if (newButton !== null) {
    newButton.classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
  
function changeToPicture(pictureIndex) {
  // console.log(`Changing picture to index ${pictureIndex}`);
  // Change the image
  image.src = `http://lorempixel.com/320/200/cats/${pictureIndex}`;
  moveHighlight(pictureIndex);
  
  // Use a modulo operator to turn 4 (number of pictures) back to 0 and add 1 so the range becomes 1...number of pictures.
  pictureIndex = (pictureIndex % numberOfPictures) + 1;
  
  // Set a timeout of X ms after which the changeToPicture method is called again, this time with the new value of pictureIndex.
  timeoutId = setTimeout((newIndex) => changeToPicture(newIndex), delayBetweenPictures, [pictureIndex]);
}


function onSlideControlClicked(event) {
  const
    button = event.target,
    index = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-index'));
    
  // Clear the timeout or else we will be starting another timeout loop.
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  // Change to the picture for which the user clicked the button.
  changeToPicture(index);
}

slideControl.addEventListener('click', onSlideControlClicked);
changeToPicture(initialPicture);
```

```css
button {
  font: inherit;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style:none;
}

li + li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.highlight {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #000;
}
```

```html
<img id="slideshow">

<p>Jump to slide:</p>
<ul id="slide-control">
  <li><button type="button" data-index="1">1</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" data-index="2">2</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" data-index="3">3</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" data-index="4">4</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My new code work:

HTML :

```
 <section class="testimony">
    <div class="testimony__content">

      <article class="testimony__content--pers">
        <div class="pers"></div>
        <p class="comment"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. </p>
        <p class="name">Gabrielle, 35 ans</p>
      </article>

      <aside class="aside hide-xs">
        <div class="bulletOrange pers1" onclick="stopSliderPers(0)"></div>
        <div class="bulletGrey pers2" onclick="stopSliderPers(1)"></div>
        <div class="bulletGrey pers3" onclick="stopSliderPers(2)"></div>
      </aside>
    </div>

  </section>
```

JS:

```
var persData = [{
    src: "./assets/img/pers-1.png",
    comment: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. ",
    name: "Gabrielle, 35 ans"
  },
  {
    src: "./assets/img/pers-2.jpg",
    comment: "Suspendisse leo neque, egestas vitae dapibus sit amet, lacinia sed lorem. Aliquam quam odio, eleifend sed lectus. ",
    name: "Bernard, 28 ans"
  },
  {
    src: "./assets/img/pers-3.jpg",
    comment: "Maecenas posuere velit in suscipit lobortis. Nam luctus justo quis aliquam molestie. Suspendisse sit amet blandit leo. ",
    name: "Julie, 22 ans"
  }
];


var intervalPers;
index = 1;

function changePers(index) {
  var indexUse = index + 1;

  var pers = persData[index];


  $(".testimony__content--pers .pers").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + pers.src + ")").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $(".testimony__content--pers .comment").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).text(pers.comment).fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $(".testimony__content--pers .name").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).text(pers.name).fadeIn(1000);
  });

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (i === indexUse) {
      $(".testimony .aside .pers" + i).removeClass("bulletGrey");
      $(".testimony .aside .pers" + i).addClass("bulletOrange");
    } else {
      $(".testimony .aside .pers" + i).removeClass("bulletOrange");
      $(".testimony .aside .pers" + i).addClass("bulletGrey");
    }
  }
}

function startSliderPers(index) {
  intervalPers = setInterval(function(){
    if (index > 2) {
      index = 0;
    } else if(index < 0){
      index = 2;
    }
    changePers(index);
    index++;
  }, 5000);
}
startSliderPers(index);

function stopSliderPers(index) {
  clearInterval(intervalPers);
  changePers(index);

  setTimeout(function(){
    index++;
      startSliderPers(index);
  },5000);
}
```